# How to add a library in C++ correctly?

Tags: c++, cmake

For my C++ Project I have a directory structure as follows (project name is "taxonomy"):

- taxonomy
- - CMakelists.txt
- - main.cpp
- - some_library
- - - CMakelists.txt
- - - include
- - - - all.hpp
- - - - subdirectory
- - - - - - someCode.cpp

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(taxonomy)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

add_executable(taxonomy main.cpp)
target_include_directories(taxonomy PUBLIC some_library)
```

The problem I am facing is that all.hpp has code like #include "subdirectory/someCode.cpp". When in my main function I write "#include "some_library/include/all.hpp"" then it will not find those files.
I guess I have to tell CMakeLists somehow that I want to add the path "some_library/include" as "main path". But how do I do that?

Comment: `target_include_directories(taxonomy PUBLIC some_library/include)`?

Comment: The inclusion `#include "subdirectory/someCode.cpp"` looks suspicious, as it includes the **source** file (with `.cpp` extension). Normally, only **header** files should be included via `#include`. As for making inclusion to work, you need to specify an include directory which would **contain** file `some_library/include/all.hpp`. The directory `some_library` doesn't fit for that purpose, as there is no file `some_library/some_library/include/all.hpp`. But the directory `.` (or `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}`) fits: there is file `./some_library/include/all.hpp`.

Comment: Possibly `target_include_directories(taxonomy PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` but that won't fix the CMakeLists.txt for the library itself which is not shown here.

Comment: Thank you very much for both comments. target_include_directories(taxonomy PUBLIC some_library/include) worked and thanks to comment 2 I know why :)